# Converting Hexadecimal to decimal get the incorrect result

Tags: hex

Currently write a program to convert hexadecimal to decimal. Below are my code:

```
 public  class HexTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
         int z = 0xDeadCafe;
         System.out.println("z = " + z);
       }
    }
```

When I run my program, it show me: `z = -559035650`

However, when I test `0xDeadCafe` using Hex to decimal converter it give me different result which is `3735931646`. May I know is it something wrong with my code and cause me get the incorrect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here - `int` is a *signed* type, and as the top bit of your value is 1 (because `D` is greater than 7) you end up with a negative number.

The simplest way to see the unsigned value would be to use a `long` instead:

```
long z = 0xdeadcafeL;
```

Note the `L` here to make it a long literal - otherwise it's treated as an `int` literal and *then* converted to a `long` - leaving it as a negative number again.

An alternative would be to use the integer literal but mask it with `0xFFFFFFFFL` to turn it into a long without making it negative:

```
int z = 0xdeadcafe;
long x = z & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, now I already change int to long, but it still give me the signed value. May I know how to get the unsigned value?

Comment: @Ian: I've shown two different versions - either use a long literal to start with, or mask it with a "bottom 32 bits set" long.